# Scala : AnyVal inferred instead of InputStream

Tags: scala, types

Very simple Scala 2.11.7 function and I have no idea, why there is a type
inference error:

```
a type was inferred to be `AnyVal`; this may indicate a programming error.
def isWrapper(is: FileInputStream): InputStream = {
                                                ^
```

Although `PushbackInputStream` -> `FilterInputStream` -> `InputStream`
and `GZIPInputStream` -> `InflaterInputStream` -> `FilterInputStream` -> `InputStream`.

```
def isWrapper(is: FileInputStream): InputStream = {
  val pb = new PushbackInputStream(is, 2)
  val signature = new Array[Byte](2)
  pb.read(signature)
  pb.unread(signature)
  if (signature.sameElements(Array(0x1F, 0x8B))) {
    new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(pb))
  } else {
    pb
  }
}
```

Error says that result of evaluation of the `if` block could not be `InputStream`. Why do I get wrong? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this LUB:

```
scala> (new Array[Byte](2)).sameElements(Array(0x1F, 0x8B))
<console>:12: warning: a type was inferred to be `AnyVal`; this may indicate a programming error.
       (new Array[Byte](2)).sameElements(Array(0x1F, 0x8B))
                                              ^
res1: Boolean = false
```

Look at the "full" signature in the docs to see the pernicious `B >: A` bound.

Not sure why the caret is off, off-hand.

Comment: It makes me long for the old days when everything was an int. I'll look into creating an issue for the crappy caret.

Comment: I have just created one. Please edit it if necessary.

Comment: Thx, I just added a minimally.